# How to implement a Recurrent neural network (RNN) on FPGA

Tags: fpga, system-verilog

For learning purposes, I want to implement a Gated recurrent unit (GRU)-RNN accelerator on FPGA. Can anyone please share how should I start and the learning path I should follow? I want to use Xilinx Zynq 7010 and prefer using system Verilog coding. I have already gone through a couple of online tutorials but don't have a clear idea about the whole process.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

The neural networks need

- multiply_accumulate units
- linked lists (or arrays) of which signal sources feed into a particular neuron
- some non_linearity, such as sigmoid or even the simple "set ooutput to zero, if input is negative"
- some counters that are aware of the size of the input elements of each layer of neurons

Basically, you must define the complete and fully detailed algorithm, then use standard hardware modules (RAM, registor files, MACs, busses, counters, shifters) to implement your fully detailed algorithm.